# Users are created with the flag "ORACLE_MAINTAINED" = "Y"

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, flyway

I am trying to create a new user in Oracle with the following script, executed as the 'SYSTEM' user:

```
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
create user my_user identified by my_password;
```

I am aware that this user does not have any grants yet, but I am wondering why Oracle creates this user as a system user. If I run the following query:

```
select USERNAME, ORACLE_MAINTAINED from SYS.ALL_USERS where username = 'my_user'
```

then I am receiving the result

```
USERNAME                  ORACLE_MAINTAINED
------------------------- -
MY_USER                   Y
```

I am using flyway to handle the schema which belongs to the user, and it refuses to clean up my schema because it assumes that the schema is system maintained, due to the 'ORACLE_MAINTAINED' flag. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;`?

Comment: I did not want to create a user without the c## prefix and did as described in this article: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_multi_tenant_local_common_users.htm You are right with pointing this out, if I create a non-local user with the C## prefix, everything works just fine.

Comment: Patient: Doctor, it hurts when I do that. Doctor: DON'T DO THAT!!!!

Comment: So the teaching is, underscore parameters (I.e. those starting with `_`) are intended for use only under guidance of Oracle Support. They are undocumented and not intended to be used in Production applications, because they can have undesirable side-effects when used injudiciously (as this question demonstrates). Unfortunately their clandestine nature makes them attractive, and the internet doesn't help here. Basically, don't use them unless you fully understand the ramifications.